# Possible to block payment through stripe-node + webhooks?

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

**Scenario:**

- I'm listening to Stripe webhook events via the [Stripe Node.js library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripe).
- My product is set up as a subscription.
- My checkout page is hosted through a [payment link](https://stripe.com/payments/payment-links).
- Since payment link pages require no registration and have no CAPTCHA, they are a prime tool for card testers.
- All fraudulent transactions can be traced to a number of email domains.
- I'm not paying for [Radar for Fraud Teams](https://stripe.com/radar).

**Question:**

How can I leverage the webhook event listeners I'm already using to block a payment if the customer's email domain matches a domain in a block list that I maintain?

Solutions I've considered:

- Immediately delete the invoice after the `invoice.created` event. Unfortunately, this won't work because [you can't delete invoices created by subscriptions](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/issues/657).
- Cancel the [PaymentIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/cancel). I'm not sure if this is possible through payment links because I need to separate payment authorization and capture by setting `capture_method: 'manual'` through the API, and I haven't found a way to configure payment links to manual capture. I need to research this more.
- Expire the checkout session before it's completed. This is a promising solution, but I don't see a `checkout.session.started` webhook event I can listen to in order to get the checkout session ID (`cs_*`) that is required to [expire the checkout session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/expire).

Does anyone out there have a good solution to mitigate card testing headaches using Stripe payment links?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think there is a great answer for you if you are committed to using the current Stripe integration.  [Stripe Payment Links](https://stripe.com/docs/payment-links) attempt to reduce as much friction as possible between the initial click and the processing of the payment.  That being said, Stripe uses a large number of tools to monitor and prevent card testing [by default](https://stripe.com/docs/disputes/prevention/card-testing#optimize-integration) so you may be better protected than you expect.

That being said, if you want to prevent payment based on email domain you may need to either pay for [Radar](https://stripe.com/radar) and write your own custom [rules](https://stripe.com/docs/radar/rules) or switch to collecting customer email as part of some authentication system in your own integration.

Fundamentally, to implement your own block/validation you need to either use the Stripe functionality (i.e. Radar) or collect the customer email at some point where you have control.  For the initial subscription sign-up the first invoice is automatically generated and finalized and the payment attempted before you have a chance to intervene.

Comment: I'm finding this to be true after reading https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=35682534. However, I expected them to at least offer CAPTCHA. Pretty disappointed and might look at migrating to another payment provider.